# How to use AWS for Fluent Bit debug images?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fluent-bit

Has anybody use AWS-for-fluentbit debug images ? I have been following this above debugging method for the usecase I'm working on.

I want to capture EKS cluster container logs to S3 bucket. However, I am running into error -

```
[2023/08/30 21:25:48] [error] [aws_credentials] Shared credentials file /root/.aws/credentials does not exist
[2023/08/30 21:25:48] [error] [aws_credentials] Failed to retrieve credentials for AWS Profile default
```

I am trying to use IAM role for Kubernetes Service Account that's already set on the cluster but my deployed fluent-bit pods are unable to authenticate to AWS.

To debug this I am following https://github.com/aws/aws-for-fluent-bit/tree/mainline#using-the-debug-images so I could capture the core dump to upload these logs to S3 bucket. Should I recreate a new image only for S3 bucket fluentbit-conf ?